# Invoking localized user controls which are stored in a dll

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, localization, user-controls

My solution is referencing dlls from other solutions. In these "external" solutions are user controls which are localized. In my own solution I'm using these user controls by performing the following steps for each user control I want to show on screen:

- Get the type of the usercontrol from the assembly
- Use Activator.CreateInstance to create an instance of the usercontrol
- Invoke an initialize method inside the class (which does a bit of custom stuff)

After that I show the user control.

Now my problem is that the user control is ALWAYS in english. Even if I set "language" on the control itself to french or german it is still always in english (if on the other hand I don't reference the user control project dll but instead compile the user control as .exe (with appropriate start methods) it is displayed correctly in the correct language).

Now my question is: What am I overlooking here? Thus how can I get the user controls to localize correctly there? *(like mentioned as an in project solution it works, but when I use these user controls as external dlls I run into the problem that the default message is used instead of the localized one)*

Comment: Are you forget to copy the _satellites resources dll_ for the external dll? I am not sure but there should be some files like that.

Comment: also tried copying the de folder which contains a messages.dll but no change there if you mean something like that